# horizontal scroll in PDF generated using PDF Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn

I have generated a PDF using prawn. Issue is when I add more columns to the table, the pdf does not show horizontal scroll bar. Thus I am not able to see the column added to the right.

Has anyone faced similar issue or know a work around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PDF would not have a scroll bar, you would need to increase the width of the page by specifying the page_size option during creation.

Comment: That was a good pointer , I was using prawn_to so had to do it in my controller 
pranwto :prawn => {:page_size => [1000, 768]}

it did the trick